# Is it possible to perform an action once in 3 days with Arduino?

Tags: arduino

How to develop a portable device (home needs) that would once in exactly 3 days perform motor rotation N degrees right and than N degrees back? I wonder is it possible to develop such thing with Arduino API and if it is what is minimal components I need to have to build such device?

Comment: It most certainly looks possible, though i couldn't find code or anything on the blog post: http://andres-leon.blogspot.de/2009/04/my-first-arduino-project-diy-automatic.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a timer as [simple timer](http://playground.arduino.cc/Code/SimpleTimer). Also, take a look to http://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=143730.0.